# Javascript toggling time type

Tags: javascript, datetime

So recently, for fun and to learn more about Javascript since I haven't ever done much web development, I've been making a site which will function as a clock which picks a color by making a color hex code from the time. Fairly basic, but I'm having a bit of an issue with a feature I want to implement.

A feature I'd like to have is to use a button on the webpage to toggle between UTC and local time. To accomplish this, I have the button (onclick) multiply a number by -1, to have a positive and negative representing each state. I have verified through console.log that the value itself is changed, but there is no visible change in the time being displayed.

So, I'd appreciate it if someone could take a look. Perhaps I'm misunderstanding how the code itself flows, or repeats.

Thanks! I can put up the HTML if need be, but I think only the JS will be necessary.

```
var h, m, s;

window.onload = function startTime() {
    var today = new Date();
    var buttonHasBeenPressed = -1; // -1 = false


    document.getElementById("utcbtn").onclick = function() {
        buttonHasBeenPressed = buttonHasBeenPressed * -1; // reverses value
        console.log(buttonHasBeenPressed);
    }

    if (buttonHasBeenPressed == 1) {
        getUTCTime(today);
    } else {
        getNormalTime(today);
    }

    h = checkTime(h);
    m = checkTime(m);
    s = checkTime(s);


    var timeString = "" + h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
    var colorString = "#" + h + m + s;

    document.getElementById("main").innerHTML = timeString;
    document.getElementById("hexcolor").innerHTML = colorString;
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = colorString;

    var t = setTimeout(startTime, 500);

}

function checkTime(i) {
    if (i < 10) {i = "0" + i};  // add zero in front of numbers < 10
        return i;
}

function getUTCTime(today) {
    h = today.getUTCHours();
    m = today.getUTCMinutes();
    s = today.getUTCSeconds();
}

function getNormalTime(today) {
    h = today.getHours();
    m = today.getMinutes();
    s = today.getSeconds();
}
```

Like I said as far as javascript I'm pretty much a novice, so this code probably isn't all that great - suggestions to improve it are always welcome!

Comment: Just curious, why aren't you using a boolean for something that is clearly true/false? Also, you are only running all of the code to start the clock `onload`. I don't see where you're calling it again when you click the button. All you're doing is printing something to the console.

Comment: @Antiga Yeah thinking more about the code I'll be using a boolean, just haven't had much time to refine it. At the time I think I was thinking that that seemed more clearly "toggleable" to me, but will change that. As far as onload, I've been somewhat confused as to what exactly `setTimeout()` is doing. I found it as a way to make sure the clock updates, so I assumed it loops it in one way or another, however it seems that may be incorrect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your code is not changing from UTC to normal time, is because you are setting a timeout for `var t = setTimeout(startTime, 500);`. In `startTime` you are immediately setting it to -1 `var buttonHasBeenPressed = -1; // -1 = false`. So each time it runs you set it back to -1. If you move the `var buttonHasBeenPressed = -1; // -1 = false` outside of the `startTime` function it will work. See updated code.

```
var h, m, s;
var buttonHasBeenPressed = -1; // -1 = false
window.onload = function startTime() {
  var today = new Date();

  document.getElementById("utcbtn").onclick = function() {
    buttonHasBeenPressed = buttonHasBeenPressed * -1; // reverses value
    console.log(buttonHasBeenPressed);
  }

  if (buttonHasBeenPressed == 1) {
    getUTCTime(today);
  } else {
    getNormalTime(today);
  }

  h = checkTime(h);
  m = checkTime(m);
  s = checkTime(s);


  var timeString = "" + h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
  var colorString = "#" + h + m + s;

  document.getElementById("main").innerHTML = timeString;
  document.getElementById("hexcolor").innerHTML = colorString;
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = colorString;

  var t = setTimeout(startTime, 500);

}

function checkTime(i) {
  if (i < 10) {
    i = "0" + i
  }; // add zero in front of numbers < 10
  return i;
}

function getUTCTime(today) {
  h = today.getUTCHours();
  m = today.getUTCMinutes();
  s = today.getUTCSeconds();
}

function getNormalTime(today) {
  h = today.getHours();
  m = today.getMinutes();
  s = today.getSeconds();
}
```

Edit: 
I would also make `buttonHasBeenPressed` a boolean and setup a `init()` function where you add the onclick handler and start `startTime` so you are not adding the onclick handler each time.

```
var h, m, s;
var buttonHasBeenPressed = false;

window.onload = init;

function init() {

  document.getElementById("utcbtn").onclick = function() {
    buttonHasBeenPressed = !buttonHasBeenPressed;
    console.log(buttonHasBeenPressed);
  }

  startTime();

}

function startTime() {

  var today = new Date();

  if (buttonHasBeenPressed) {
    getUTCTime(today);
  } else {
    getNormalTime(today);
  }

  h = checkTime(h);
  m = checkTime(m);
  s = checkTime(s);


  var timeString = "" + h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
  var colorString = "#" + h + m + s;

  document.getElementById("main").innerHTML = timeString;
  document.getElementById("hexcolor").innerHTML = colorString;
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = colorString;

  var t = setTimeout(startTime, 500);

}

function checkTime(i) {
  if (i < 10) {
    i = "0" + i
  }; // add zero in front of numbers < 10
  return i;
}

function getUTCTime(today) {
  h = today.getUTCHours();
  m = today.getUTCMinutes();
  s = today.getUTCSeconds();
}

function getNormalTime(today) {
  h = today.getHours();
  m = today.getMinutes();
  s = today.getSeconds();
}
```

Comment: This fixed it, thanks! Not sure why I didn't catch that!

Answer (score 1):

`buttonHasBeenPressed` and `setTimeout` should not have been local to the startTime function.

Here's a working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aoLuoL78/).